# Why is my sum for two columns in psql incorrect?

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

I am trying to get the sum of two columns in psql

```
    select id as id, name as name, count(winner_id) as winner_count,
 (count(winner_id) +count(loser_id)) as total_matches from player left join 
matches on matches.winner_id = player.id group by winner_id, player.name,player.id, 
matches.loser_id;")
```

The total matches count should be the total or winner_id and loser_id in the matches table.

But it's incorrect.

It should return 1 match for all players, but instead it is returning 2 matches for the players who have won and 0 matches for the players who lost.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

`count()` counts the number of times that a value is not `NULL`.  So, the two `count()`s will probably return the same value.  I suspect you want something like this:

```
select id, name,
       sum(case when id = winner_id then 1 else 0 end) as winner_count,
       count(m.id) as total_matches
from player p left join 
     matches m
     on m.winner_id = p.id
group by p.name, p.id;
```

Comment: Thanks! That's closer to what I was looking for. If the players are only entered but haven't yet had a match, then it should return 0 for the count, but I will try to modify that myself. When there are matches though it works, so it's gotten me closer. Thanks!

Comment: @John . . . I the problem is `total_matches`, that just requires fixing what is being counted.